# Someone can solve my jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know very less amount of jquery can someone help me.. I have written the code but failed in last thing, that

- image(from lest side) two and three should fade out and first image will slide left while clicking on button1. and same for button tow and three.
- on clicking button1 if the first sections are active (left image and bottom text) then they should fade and re-appear with sliding effect.

```js
$(".c2").css("display", "none");
$(".c3").css("display", "none");
$(".image03").css("display", "none");
$(".image02").css("display", "none");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img01').click(function() {
        $(".image01").show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        });
        $(".c1").show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        });
        $(".c2").css("display", "none");
        $(".c3").css("display", "none");
        $(".image03").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".image02").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
    });

    $('.img02').click(function() {
        $(".image02").show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 500);
        $(".c2").show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 500);
        $(".c1").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".c3").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".image03").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".image01").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
    });
    $('.img03').click(function() {
        $(".image03").show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 500);
        $(".c3").show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 500);
        $(".c1").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".c2").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".image02").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
        $(".image01").effect('fade', 200).css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

```css
.slide {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.img01, .img02, .img03 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
         <div class="img-show">
                <div class="image01 slide"><img src="http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/panorama/nature/Rivers/RiversS.gif" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="image02 slide"><img src="http://shalomisraeltours.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Amud-Stream-Nature-Reserve-200x100.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="image03 slide"><img src="http://naturepreserves.ohiodnr.gov/portals/dnap/WebSitesCreative_PostIt/27763/ec1ef173-8b35-414c-a8c3-ff06d141590e.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 img-ico">
         <div class="img01 col-xs-4"><img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/netimagebutton/ExampleButton.png" width="43" height="31" />Design</div>
            <div class="img02 col-xs-4"><img src="http://getsafesea.com/images/submit-button.png" width="43" height="31" />Design</div>
            <div class="img03 col-xs-4"><img src="http://softwaresupportserviceshost.com/caaconnect/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/06/login-button.png" width="43" height="31" />Design</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>                    
            <div class="content">
             <div class="contentshow c1">This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.</div>
                <div class="contentshow c2">This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.</div>
                <div class="contentshow c3">This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--container-->
```

Comment: I count three document.ready()'s in your jQuery, one is sufficient.

Comment: I have edited and kept one document.ready().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jQuery [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) method will give you what you need. I have implemented a possible solution, hope I have understood your requirements. I have also taken the opportunity to refactor your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Reload('.image01', '.c1'); // first load

  $('.img01').click(function() {
    Reload('.image01', '.c1');
  });

  $('.img02').click(function() {
    Reload('.image02', '.c2');
  });
  $('.img03').click(function() {
    Reload('.image03', '.c3');
  });
});

function Reload(imageClass, contentClass) {
  $(".c1").fadeOut();
  $(".c2").fadeOut();
  $(".c3").fadeOut();
  $(".image01").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(".image02").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(".image03").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(imageClass).show("slide", {
          direction: "left"
        }, 500);
        $(contentClass).show("slide", {
          direction: "right"
        }, 500);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Please see my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pcv750p0/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew Ashton.

Comment: Andrew, Can you please say me why the code is being written one inside another as

>$(".image01").fadeOut("slow", function () {
>        $(".image02").fadeOut("slow", function () {
>            $(".image03").fadeOut("slow", function () {
> //Code goes here.
>            });
>         });
>});
while writing at outside as separate each section it is not working properly.

Comment: Yes, the code within the function will only execute when the fadeOut() has completed. For example, image02 will only start to fade out when image01 has finished fading out, and image03 will only start to fade out when image02 has finished fading out. When image03 has finished fading out, we know for sure that we are ready to reload the required image and text. Without this, you get some unwanted results - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pcv750p0/2/

Comment: Yes i have tried locally and i got that result as in fiddle. Thanks a lot Andrew Ashton